# new T(...) vs. std::make_unique<T>(...).release()

Tags: c++, constructor, unique-ptr

I was looking at the [companion code](https://github.com/CppCon/CppCon2014/blob/master/Presentations/Hourglass%20Interfaces%20for%20C%2B%2B%20APIs/code/hairpoll.cpp) of the ["Hourglass API" talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PVYdHDm0q6Y) of CppCon 2014, which is about providing a C API to a C++ library mainly by wrapping member functions of a class with functions that have a C signature.

Among other things, I have been intrigued by how the object is constructed. In the function `hairpoll_construct` that constructs a new `hairpoll` object, the pointer is obtained by

```
std::make_unique<hairpoll>(person).release()
```

which is actually called within a function that handles exceptions. A simpler way would be to resort to a plain

```
new hairpoll(person)
```

What are the scenarios where the former is preferable? Does this have to do with how this peticuliar API works or is this more general than this?

Comment: It might be to no longer use `new` when possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the constructor throws, the `new` expression ¹deallocates the memory automatically before passing on the exception.

The author probably thought that it was necessary to use a temporary `unique_ptr` to achieve this.

I'm not aware of any advantage.

<sup><sub>¹ Unless the class defines an allocator function, an `operator new`, without a corresponding deallocator function, `operator delete`. Once this was the case for the debug functionality in Microsoft's MFC class library. Memory was leaked, but only in debug builds.</sub></sup>

Comment: Regarding your footnote, I am not sure the author (S. Du Toit) had this scenario in mind in his avoidance of `new` because `hairpoll_destruct` uses `delete`.

Comment: @user1735003: Well, the `unique_ptr` would not have helped anyway. With an exception from the constructor the pointer member in the `unique_ptr` isn't even assigned/initialized. The exception stops whatever is going on there, and the `unique_ptr` is not completely constructed, so its destructor is not called, so the `unique_ptr` will not participate in cleanup.